# Avoid using environment variables when doing variable imports

Tags: python, environment-variables, directory-structure

I have been working with a project for which I give the choice of using two backends (backends 1 and 2, let's say) following what they do in [this project](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/load_backend.py). However, that project counts on having already defined environment variables for deciding which backend to use before executing the code. It would not be the case for the code I'm writing.

I would like to know if there is any alternative to use environment variables in this scenario so that, on execution time, I can load one backend or another depending on the value of a variable. The general structure of my project is as follows:

[image: Project]

I thought of directly setting the environment variable directly in the python code (`os.environ['NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE'] = 'BACKEND 1'`), but that feels potentially insecure and I ***really*** dislike the idea, even if the variable name is... unique. Given this need, I would like to know if it is possible to have some kind of variable spanning different files so that, when I *do* import a module, the `__init__.py` file can disambiguate between the backends.

**PS**: Maybe what I'm doing makes no sense whatsoever.

---

[UPDATE] Some more information about the problem, reduced to its minimal extension. My main file processes some data and is the following:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from utils.loader import load_data
from utils.do import do_stuff

def main(config):
    data = load_data(config)
    do_stuff(config, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Retrieve input data
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--backend', type=str, default='backend 1', help='backend to use')
    inputs = parser.parse_args()

    config = "backend 1" if inputs.backend == "1" else "backend 2"

    # Call main function
    main(config)
```

The data loader `load_data(config)` I guess is not important for this. Then, the file containing `do_stuff(data)` is the following:

```
import backend

def do_stuff(config, data):
    # Do some really important stuff that is coded in backend 1 and backend 2
    a = backend.do_something(data)
    print(a)
```

It simply loads the backend (!!!) and does something. The `do_stuff(data)` function itself does something coded in either backend 1 or backend 2:

```
def do_something(data):
    data.values = "Value obtained through functions of 'BACKEND 1' (same function names and inputs, different backends used)"
```

and

```
def do_something(data):
    data.values = "Value obtained through functions of 'BACKEND 2' (same function names and inputs, different backends used)"
```

Finally, the backend module has in itself the following `__init__.py` file:

```
from .load_backend import do_something
```

Which loads from the `load_backend.py` file, which simply disambiguates the backend ***given an environmental variable***:

````
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

# Default backend: backend 1
if 'ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE' in os.environ:
    _BACKEND = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE']
else:
    _BACKEND = 'backend 1'

# Import backend functions.
if _BACKEND == "backend 1":
    sys.stderr.write('Using backend 1\n')
    from .backend_1 import *
elif _BACKEND == "backend 2":
    sys.stderr.write('Using backend 2\n')
    from .backend_2 import *
else:
    raise ValueError('Unable to import backend : ' + str(_BACKEND))


def backend():
    """Publicly accessible method
    for determining the current backend.
    # Returns
        String, the name of the backend
    # Example
    ```python
        >>> backend.backend()
        'backend 1'
    ```
    """
    return _BACKEND
````

What I want is to reduce this last environment variable with anything else, but I don't know what can I use.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're hung up on environment variables here. That project just uses them to determine the path to load but why do you think you couldn't use a normal variable in exactly the same way?

Comment: Hi, Daniel, thanks for taking interest. Maybe I'm not knowledgeable enough to see it but, since the disambiguation would be done in `ProjectX/backend/__init__.py` and I would be defining the variable you mention in `ProjectX/main.py`, I'm not sure on how to pass that variable from `main.py` to `__init__.py`, although it might be really obvious and I'm not seeing it. The idea is that I want to be able to use `import backend` and forget about it, but how would I be able to disamiguate during an import?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to have in main.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just updated the question for improved context. Thanks!

Comment: please provide all code *as formatted text*, please do not use screen shots

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: BTW, what security issues are you concerned out wrt. environment variables? They're local to a process -- sure, any other process under the same account can read them under normal kernel settings, but any other process under the same account can connect with a debugger and read *all* your memory, so that's not exactly different in any way.

Comment: (Yes, environment variables are also copied to child processes -- but that too is common to all memory that hasn't explicitly been flagged to not be mapped on fork; really, the only thing that makes them unusual is not being discarded on an `execv`-family call, and having a dedicated region for storage rather than being on the stack or heap).

Comment: BTW, `_BACKEND = os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE', 'backend 1')` would avoid the need for an `if`, by using the `get()` method's default argument. In general, this code is a lot longer / more verbose than it has any reason to be (if you have a `backend` function, why not put *all* the logic in there?)

Comment: (I also question why you'd need to include a command-line parser in a *minimal* reproducer, or more than one module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @DanielRoseman asked, I would just pass the backend argument around. For example in `load_backend`, while changing your code as litte as possible:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

def backend(backend):
    """Returns the wanted backend module"""
    # Import backend functions.
    if backend == "backend 1":
        sys.stderr.write('Using backend 1\n')
        from . import backend_1 as backend_module
    elif backend == "backend 2":
        sys.stderr.write('Using backend 2\n')
        from . import backend_2 as backend_module
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unable to import backend : ' + str(_BACKEND))

    return backend_module
```

An improvement could be to use `importlib` to dynamically import the backend and move the magic strings to a constant:

```py
...
import importlib

BACKENDS = {
    "backend 1": "backend_1",
    "backend 2": "backend_2"
}

def load_backend(backend):
    try:
        module = importlib.import_module(
            BACKENDS[backend]
        )
    except KeyError:
        raise ImportError('Unable to import backend : %s' % backend)

    sys.stderr.write('Using %s\n' % backend)
    return module
```

So you can do this in the `do_stuff` file:

```py
import load_backend

def do_stuff(config, data):
    # Do some really important stuff that is coded in backend 1 and backend 2
    backend = load_backend.backend(config)
    a = backend.do_something(data)
    print(a)
```

---

Another way to go about this is to use a singleton pattern, where you set the backend variable once (and other settings you want broadly available):

in a `settings.py` or whereever:

```py
class SettingSingleton(object):
    _backend = None

    def __new__(cls, backend=None, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._backend = cls._backend or backend
        return super(SettingsSingleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def backend(self):
        return self._backend
```

You can initialize that in the main.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from utils.loader import load_data
from utils.do import do_stuff
from settings import SettingSingleton


def main(config):
    SettingsSingleton(backend=config)
    data = load_data(config)
    do_stuff(config, data)

...
```

Now you can do something like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys

from settings import SettingsSingleton

_BACKEND = SettingsSingleton().backend

# Import backend functions.
if _BACKEND == "backend 1":
    sys.stderr.write('Using backend 1\n')
    from .backend_1 import *
elif _BACKEND == "backend 2":
    sys.stderr.write('Using backend 2\n')
    from .backend_2 import *
else:
    raise ValueError('Unable to import backend : ' + str(_BACKEND))
```

Downside to this is that it is somewhat implicit.